# Facebook session key issue

Tags: facebook, api

I am using

> http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=appkey&connect_display=popup&v=1.0&next="myurl"&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&session_key_only=true&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access``

But it does not redirect me to my url and redirect to facebook feeds page

Earlier it was working and I am getting session key but from last week it does not redirect me to my given url

Answer (score 1):

The /login.php endpoint is no more available – you’ll have to adapt your flow to implement login as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/